# JSHint throwing undefined is not a function in GitHub's Atom Editor

Tags: javascript, jshint, atom-editor

For some odd reason JsHint is throwing me a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` inside of Atom Editor when I run the simplest line of code..

```
function myName (name) {
  name = 'brent';
  return name;
}
console.log(myName());
```

Any suggestions!

Even flags an error when noting using `console.log();`

```
function myName(name) {
  name = 'brent';
  return name;
}
myName();
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps but it works in jslint but has errors.

Comment: @dibs thanks. Yes I know. I just don't like the use strict in every function inside of jslint do you know a work around? What are you using?

Comment: I just use jslint on default settings and match what it deems as necessary. However you can disable the 'use strict' requirement.

Comment: It doesn't know about console.log by default. You have to tell it.

Comment: @dibs fair enough...How do you disable the use strict? Are you using atom?

Comment: I don't use atom. I use sublime text with jslint and I also use jslint.com which has switches down the bottom for altering what it checks for.

Comment: @dibs yeah..I am about 2 seconds away from giving up on atom again...dam..she's just not for me no matter how hard I try. I use jshint is sublime 3 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Have you checked the stack trace in the error message?